# Symfony2 Routes doesn't find route (multilingual)

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'would like to redirect a visitor to the Project:index page if he types in www.url.com/project or www.url.com/en/project

Somehow it doesn't find the routes I devined (yes cache was cleared several times)

Here are the routes:

```
dbe_projectLang:
    path:     /project/
    defaults: { _controller: DbeDonaciBundle:Project:root }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de


dbe_project:
    resource: "@DbeDonaciBundle/Resources/config/routing/project.yml"
    prefix:     /{_locale}/project/
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de
```

And here is the route controller <- this one works normally

```
public function rootAction(Request $request) {
    $locale = $request -> getLocale();
    return $this -> redirect($this -> generateUrl('dbe_project', array('_locale' => $locale)));
}
```

Here is the error message it get:

```
No route found for "GET /project/"
```

Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as described above works. It was only necessary to clear the cache (it's always needed with all changes in routing):

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```